# Use a plural noun to describe a second one

Tags: plural-forms, adjuncts

I want to explain `char *szArray[]`, it denotes :

- In singular noun, *an array of which each element is a pointer to a zero-terminated string.*
- In plural noun, *an array whose all elements are pointers to zero-terminated strings.*

Well/As you know(PS, pet phrase for people? I just use it to express a soothing mood), English is not my first language and I cannot tell which is legitimate or neither.
Just as ["No worry" vs. "No worries"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/214085/no-worry-vs-no-worries). I wonder what feelings you might have when you speaking English hear I say an awkward phrase or sentence.( Perhaps, you can easily figure out it is not idiomatic English, even if not wrong grammatically. 
Even more unfortunately, I cannot be understood )

So now I need a hand to analyse the two sentences above.

Answer (score 4):

Both of these ways of expressing your thought are acceptable, except we do not say "whose all elements" but

> ... **all of whose elements** are pointers to zero-terminated strings *OR*
>   ... **whose elements are all** pointers to zero-terminated strings.

But there's a simpler way  of expressing this:

> ... an array of pointers to zero-terminated strings.

Comment: I was thinking should we really use "all" in the sentence? I mean is there any difference if we omit the "all" from "whose elements are all"?

Comment: Good, I love a simpler way~